# Error while running the existing React Native project

Tags: react-native

So I'm opening my the existing React Native project. This is the procedure on how I opened my existing React Native project. 1st step, type the location of my project which is in the "D:\rnprojects\firstproject\". 2nd step, "react-native-start". 3rd step, I opened another cmd then locate it again into my project directory then typed "npm start".

Why when I created this project I didn't get this error just when runnning/opening my existing project.

This the error that I got: (with versions)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is only simple steps can solve your particular scenario issue quickly.

1) Install the React native cli in your project or globally.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

**OR**

```
npm install react-native --save
```

then start your project by using this command

```
npm start
```

*If any dependencies issue please follow the second solution*

2) Please make sure you're installed all dependence

```
 yarn install
```

OR

```
 npm install
```

under your project directory

I'm pretty sure your issue will fix by using 1st solution Thanks.

Comment: in "npm install react-native --save" should i install it globally or just in the project directory?

Comment: Just under the project

Answer (score 0):

it is simple:
1.`npm install`
2.`react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Here I guess you have the RN environment to run already on your side.

> 1. cd path_to_project
> 2. install packages(there are two following ways to install packages).
>      2.1 yarn install
>      2.2 npm install
>         react-native link(optional - you need to run this command if existing project use RN packages which need to link such as
>      react-native-vector-icons)
> 3. optional(if project use pods)    cd ios      pod install
> 4. react-native run-ios or react-native run-android according to the platform which you want to run on.

I don't think above is perfect instruction give you how to run the existing react-native project, But I am pleasure if give me some hints or help to you.

You can find official guide [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes npm's cache gets confused and need to reset it by using below command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also try below command:

```
npm install --save-dev react-native-cli
```

Hope it will help you.